# How do I use an instance of class DateTime to output its date?

Tags: php

I need to create a date and the I need to show it, I tried:

```
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-yy', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80')); 
echo date("d-m-yy", $myDate);
```

But nothing shows up, if I `var_dump($mydate);` it is fine, it is a correct date object

Comment: `date()` takes an integer number of seconds, not an object. Use [`$myDate->format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output the date in a string format use DateTime::format() http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
echo $myDate->format("d-m-Y");
```

`date()` is for formatting timestamp integers. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: this is what I get 20-03-0000 it is like not reading the year correctly

Comment: I just copied your format string, but you probably want either `d-m-y` or `d-m-Y`

Comment: You can see the possible format strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: i don't get it, why in a var_dump I get "2000-03-20" even if I am doing d-m-yy ?

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible. What does `usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80')` resolve to?

Comment: string(9) "20-3-2000"

Answer (score 1):

You mixed a bit stuff up in your code.

1. in line 1 you assign instance (object) of class DateTime to `$myDate` - thats ok!
2. in line 2 you want to output with `echo` the return value of the function `date()` which is a string BUT the second argument has to be a *integer* and not an object of class DateTime -- thats what you have mixed up

you can use the `format` method on the `DateTime` class to get the saved date in the way you want it and give it to echo:

```
echo $myDate->format("d-m-y");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php gives mor information about the `DateTime::format()` method.

You should gain more experience with procedural and objective programming, seems to me, that you mix some stuff up.

Also a PHP tutorial may be very helpfull

Comment: Yes indeed. Thanks Mirko

Answer (score 0):

First of all you've try like this way.(I'm little bit confused why you've used **2** yy?)

```
# you've to set the 'd-m-Y' based on your usp_get_meta() value
$myDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', usp_get_meta(false,'usp-custom-80'));
echo $myDate ->format('d-m-Y');
```

**To get why your existing code not working?**

Try to get the last error using- `var_dump(DateTime::getLastErrors());`

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/rq9tA

Comment: that is giving me a date like this 20-03-00

Comment: yes now it's ok but in the loop i always get the same dates, something like a cache thing?

Comment: @rob.m show me some codeblock of that loop, I guess I can help you to find out the issue